# Ansible overriding properties

Tags: ansible

I have a number of 3rd party supplier properties files that are provided with a release.  I would like Ansible to override some of those properties and leave others as-is.

Example of a single file (there will be a number of these with different properties)...

3rd party file

```
...
#prop1=
prop2=
...
prop17=false
```

Resultant file, after being processed by Ansible

```
...
prop1=blah blah blah
prop2=false
...
prop17=true
```

I tried using `replace` but it's getting horrendously verbose. Ideally I'm able provide a few files at different levels (group, host, etc) and they all override the supplier file.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) module for this. Example:

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    path: /path/to/file
    regexp: '^#?prop1='
    line: 'prop1=blah blah blah'
```

If you have a lot of props:

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    path: /path/to/file
    regexp: '^#?{{ item.prop }}='
    line: 'prop1={{ item.value }}'
  loop:
    - { prop: prop1, value: 'blah blah blah' }
    - { prop: prop2, value: 'false' }
    - { prop: prop17, value: 'true' }
```

Comment: Thanks @mhutter, that's pretty close to what I did with ```replace```, is there a way to do this with merging files?

Comment: The other reason I'm looking to merge files is I need to add a block of params too

Comment: Hm, you can use the [assemble](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/assemble_module.html) module to merge files, but they must be in the same directory.

Comment: And I guess that assemble won't override params?  So they will be duplicated...

Comment: Yes, assemble simply merges multiple fragments together.

Comment: Ok, will stick with the lineinfile or replace, thanks @mhutter.